# Simple Go-Ethereum Program not compiling

Tags: go-ethereum, golang

I am following this tutorial: [01-Interact with Ethereum blockchain using Golang](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EB0KkSkG5XU&list=PLay9kDOVd_x7hbhssw4pTKZHzzc6OG0e_&ab_channel=IdirDev)

When I compile the code, i get the following errors:

```
# github.com/deckarep/golang-set
../github.com/deckarep/golang-set/iterator.go:30:17: syntax error: unexpected comparable, expecting ]
../github.com/deckarep/golang-set/iterator.go:36:18: syntax error: unexpected [, expecting comma or )
../github.com/deckarep/golang-set/iterator.go:39:15: method has no receiver
../github.com/deckarep/golang-set/iterator.go:39:15: syntax error: unexpected {, expecting name or (
../github.com/deckarep/golang-set/iterator.go:51:6: missing function body
../github.com/deckarep/golang-set/iterator.go:51:17: syntax error: unexpected [, expecting (
# github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common
../github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common/test_utils.go:28:18: undefined: os.ReadFile
```

This is my code:

```
package main

import (
"context"
"fmt"
"log"

"github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient"
)
 var infuraURL = "https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/*******************"
func main(){
client, err := ethclient.DialContext(context.Background(),infuraURL)
if err!= nil {
    log.Fatal("Error to create an ether client:%v",err)
}
defer client.Close()//Prevent memory leak
block,err :=client.BlockByNumber(context.Background(),nil)
if err!= nil {
    log.Fatal("Error to get a block:%v",err)
}
fmt.Println(block.Number())
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that my GO version was 1.13, which is much older than the tutorail. My error was when I was downloading, WSL offered an easy way to download, but it was for version 1.13, when 1.18 is the current.

I recommend this tutorial for proper GO installation:
[Go Setup Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=poejKP1wTpc&ab_channel=NicJackson)